# Numpy Array Not JSON Serializable Even after tolist()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a nested list like this:

```
my_numpy_values = my_numpy_array.tolist()
>> [[1,2,3,4],
[5,6,7,8],
[9,10,11,12]]
```

I then set my preexisting dict values equal to the above so that I have:

```
my_dict
>>{'key1':[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...], 'key2':[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...],'key3'...}
```

I then simply wrapped it into a list:

```
json_data = [my_dict]
```

next:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data, outfile)
```

This is the point where I got the not json serializable error. However, from what I read `tolist()` is supposed to be supported. What should I be doing differently? Surely I do not have to write my own encoding serializer for something so simple?

**Update**

It's a little challenging to make a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example for this, please bear with me. I tried for minimal, and for whatever reason it made the error go away. Completeness may be harder to reproduce, many libraries and calculations are needed to get the values I'm working with. The best I can do is offer a screenshot of the error in action:

[image]

This is only a small part of the verbose, so amidst all the bells and whistles I missed the circular reference. I'm not sure if I have a circular reference problem **in addition** to non-json serializable problem, or if it's more of a cause and effect type of thing.

Either way, I don't under stand why my minimal `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...]` example as seen at the beginning of my post works and my real data doesn't. The only difference I can see are the values; the structure of the data looks identical. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is hard to answer without a [mcve].

Comment: Are you somehow appending the list to itself? The ellipses make me suspicious. If the list recursively contains itself, it would not be serializable. But it should give a message that says 'circular reference detected.'

Comment: Sounds like you might have gotten your shapes mixed up at some point, resulting in an array with other array objects inside.

Comment: When you say your dict looks like `{'key1':[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...], 'key2':[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...],'key3'...}`, are those "..."s actually present in your actual output, or did you put them into your example to indicate that the data is larger than just those values? If it's the latter, you probably _don't_ have a circular reference problem.

Comment: @Kevin yea the "..."s are just for the example. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot it!

Comment: I'm aware an image of code is not ideal, just in a bit of a pinch at the moment.

Comment: The word `array` appears in the error message, which makes me strongly suspect that there's still a numpy array amongst the data you're passing to `dump`. Ordinary builtin lists do not use the word `array` in their string representation. Are you sure that when you call `tolist`, it's actually making it into the dict? Remember that just calling `my_numpy_array.tolist()` will not cause `my_numpy_array` to turn into a list in-place.

Comment: @Kevin What I did was like the minimal example where I created a list by calling `.tolist()` on the existing numpy array. `my_numpy_values = my_numpy_array.tolist()`. Also `type(my_numpy_values)` returned `list`. The `array` in the error message is nonetheless troubling.

Comment: @ArashHowaida then you're still not showing the step where `my_numpy_values` turns into `my_dict`. Sooner or later we'll find the step where you're not doing what you think you're doing...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce a problem with your data nor the particular format passed to `json.dump`:

```
In [16]: test = [
    {"key1": [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]], 
     "key2": [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]], 
     "key3": [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]}
]

In [17]: with open("test.json", "w") as f:
    ...:     json.dump(test, f)
    ...:     

In [18]: !cat test.json
[{"key1": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]], "key2": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]], "key3": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]}]
```

Comment: Interesting developments, I did confirm that my minimal `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...` example does work, but when using my real data, it doesn't. I have updated my post with as much information as I could.